# Things not appearing in front of canvas (follow up)

Tags: unity, c#

Follow up/related question to: [Things disappear in front of Canvas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128907/things-disappear-in-front-of-canvas)

I'm having a very similar problem, where things are not appearing in front of my canvas. This time a particle system. I have tried the suggestions outlined in my previous questions (which worked then) but this time none of them will work:

[image]

You can see that the particle system is on top of the children and also I have added a canvas and overwritten sorting (the two suggestions in my previous post) yet the particles are not visible in front of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

For Particles, you need to alter the Renderer Sorting Order.  Specify the sort order similar to the Canvas sort order, where you would like the Particles to be.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. The sort order of Canvas is 0 and I tried setting the sort order on the particle system higher but nothing. Could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Divide your UI objects into two parts. Fixed background, gradient etc and HUD, Buttons, Popup etc.

Render fixed UI objects in a Camera screen space canvas. Render others in a Overlay screen space canvas. Scenes end up using multiple canvases usually.

Reset particle transform in inspector as you normally do for other objects.

[image]